# NPM install in docker container fails and returns "The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1"

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, npm, bin

I'm trying to deploy my dockerized MERN stack web app to my vps with gitlab CI/CD. In my react app dockerfile, when I try to install npm packages, I get this error:

*Service 'nowfront' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1*

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node as builder

# make directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . .
COPY .env .
RUN ls -li
#RUN yarn build
#CMD ["npm","run","build"]
RUN ls

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html 
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS.

Is there any solution to pass this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Dockerfile and added line 14 and it works now.

```
# pull official base image
FROM node as builder

# make directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . .
COPY .env .
RUN ls -li
#RUN yarn build
#CMD ["npm","run","build"]
RUN ls

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html 
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: In my case the first line of Dockerfile was `FROM node:latest as build-stage` and I changed it to `FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage` which fixed the problem.